# c# save System.Drawing.Graphics to file

Tags: c#, gdi+, picturebox

I have a System.Drawing.Graphics took from a picturebox.

basically I draw some lines over a background image stored into the picturebox
now I wish save a png that contains the background image and everything is drawn over there...

is there a way to do this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are drawing these lines on the Paint event then you need to create a BitMap with the BackgroundImage and call your paint function with the Bitmap's Graphics, and then call Bitmap.Save().

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(MyPictureBox.BackgroundImage);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        MyPictureBox.OnPaint(new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs(g, bmp.GetBounds());
```

Answer (score 4):

Yep, use the [Image.Save method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save.aspx) on your PictureBox's Image:

```
pictureBox.Image.Save(fullnameOfYourImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: thanks, but the Image is null... I think 'cause i've drawed some text using System.Drawing.Graphics

Comment: @ghiboz It sounds like your real problem then is how to draw onto a PictureBox image.  I'd recommend creating a new question (showing your code), but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063505/c-sharp-how-to-save-a-picturebox-control-as-a-jpeg-file-after-its-edited) will help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you can convert to a Bitmap and save it?

See this article:

[Saving System.Drawing.Graphics to a png or bmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928845/saving-system-drawing-graphics-to-a-png-or-bmp)

Comment: No, you can't convert an arbitrary Graphics to a Bitmap and save it. What the link shows, despite its title, is that USUALLY when you have a Graphics that you have been rendering to, the way to accomplish the desired result is to INSTEAD make those render calls to A GRAPHICS THAT YOU CREATED USING `Graphics.FromImage(aBitmap)`. If your code can be so arranged, then you can do `aBitmap.Save`, because you have a bitmap that you have been rendering to.