# C# Console Application - How to draw in BMP/JPG file using GDI+?

Tags: c#, jpeg, console-application, gdi+, bmp

I want to draw shapes like rectangles, arrows, text, lines in a BMP or JPG file, using a C# Console Application and GDI+. This is what I found on the web:

c# save System.Drawing.Graphics to file [c# save System.Drawing.Graphics to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621726/c-sharp-save-system-drawing-graphics-to-file)
GDI+ Tutorial for Beginners http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/gdi_plus12092005070041AM/gdi_plus.aspx
Professional C# - Graphics with GDI+ codeproject.com/Articles/1355/Professional-C-Graphics-with-GDI

But this still doesn't help me. Some of these links explains this only for a Windows Forms Application and other links are only for reference (MSDN links), explaining only classes, methods etc. in GDI+.
So how can I draw in a picture file using a C# Console Application?
Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you use the code from Windows Forms examples in your console app?  Either way you'll be doing the same thing with the System.Drawing.Graphics code.

Answer (score 9):

It is pretty straight-forward to create bitmaps in a console mode app.  Just one minor stumbling block, the project template doesn't preselect the .NET assembly you need.  Project + Add Reference, select System.Drawing

A very simple example program:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;   // NOTE: add reference!!

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100))
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
            gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
            var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
                "Example.png");
            bmp.Save(path);
        }
    }
}
```

After you run this you'll have a new bitmap on your desktop.  It is orange.  Get creative with the Graphics methods to make it look the way you want.

Comment: Sorry to say, but the program doesn't run. It gives this error: "Error 1: The name 'bmp' does not exist in the current context". What's with the squiggly brackets "{" at the end of the 7th row? And why there isn't no ";" at the end of the 6th and 7th row (the ones with the "using" statement)? I'm using .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008 Professional. Before asking the question, I added that ref. and tried to draw this way: <code>      Graphics g;
            Pen BlackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
            g.DrawRectangle(BlackPen, 1, 1, 300, 700); </code> But I didn't know what to do next!

Comment: Nothing wrong with the brackets, this is tested code.  You've modified it in a way that broke it, probably by tinkering with brackets.  You certainly should **not** declare your own Graphics object `g`.  Use the `gr` variable that was created in the using statement from Graphics.FromImage().  You won't draw to the bitmap otherwise.  Start by copying the code **exactly** as shown and verify that you get the orange bitmap.

Comment: Sorry, the way that the code si placed in the website made me see the brackets in a wrong way. I just copy-pasted all again and it Works! Thanks! What do you say about this method and why do you say that I shouldn't declare a Graphics object?   Bitmap b = new Bitmap(100, 100);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 3), 0, 0, 80, 50);
            b.Save("C:\\b.bmp");

Comment: You've got it wrong! I'll use YOUR idea! I'm just asking: what's wrong with the idea I posted (which I get from another source) and why did you said I shouldn't declare my own Graphics object?

Answer (score 2):

- Add reference to the *Assembly:  System.Drawing (in System.Drawing.dll)*.
- Add using: *Namespace:  System.Drawing*.
- Create an empty [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx), e.g. `var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);`
- Create [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) object for that [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx): `var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);`
- Use graphics object methods to draw on your bitmap, e.g. `graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 10, 10)`;
- Save your image as a file: `bitmap.Save("MyShapes.png");`

Comment: Try this for yourself to find the flaw in the directions.  There are two big mistakes.

Comment: @HansPassant: Your answer is an exact example of what is written in my answer.

Comment: Hehe, no, I didn't make those two big mistakes.  There is no assembly named System.Drawing.dll and your Save() call doesn't actually save the bitmap in the JPEG format.  Problems that can give the OP a devil of a time, especially the format problem is extremely hard to diagnose.

Comment: @HansPassant: If that is what *flaw in the directions* means, then ok. *Assembly: System.Drawing (in System.Drawing.dll)* is a sentence copied from the MSDN so it is not the *big mistake*. But the second about the image file format you're right and I will edit it from "jpg" to "png".

Comment: Ah, oops, I fumbled that one.  We'll get to the right answer eventually ;)

Comment: Thank you, yBee, for the details you gave me!