# Turning graphics into bitmap in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, save, drawing

So I've been struggling with this for a while. How can I turn a graphic that I drew into a bitmap and how can I keep it updated? I mean let's say I wanna draw some shapes and then go ahead and color some random areas using setPixel, getPixel etc by going pixel by pixel on the bitmap. I don't want the old drawings to dissapear, but to put the color on top of it if it makes sense. And also, how can I save the bitmap on the computer without getting just a black image?

I'm relatively new to c# and getting answers to these questions would mean the world to me.

Comment: Here is an answer that describes how to draw shapes to a bitmap and save it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137449/c-sharp-console-application-how-to-draw-in-bmp-jpg-file-using-gdi

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To save a Bitmap is easy

```
Bitmap pic = new Bitmap(16, 16);//16x16 picture

//draw what you want

pic.Save("name.bmp");//save the drawed Bitmap
pic.Dispose();
```

With `.Save` you save the file.
With `.Dispose` you give the ressourses free from the picture, dispose the picture when you don't use the picture anymore.